# Layout in Android should be similar to an iOS layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create for Android a row layout I have in an iOS app, at least I need to make it very similar to the iOS layout.

Here you have the iOS screenshot and the Android layout scheme:

[image]

And this is the layout code I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background="#5981b2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"       
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:text="Titulo"
        android:textSize="22dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:text="Subtitle" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleText"
        android:src="@drawable/valoracion" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon1"
        android:text="14"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/num"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num"
        android:src="@drawable/flecha" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course, any help to make the layout similar to the iOS layout is welcome.

Comment: everything is quite ok with you sketch, what's your problem?

Comment: @Salauyou, thank you for your comment, my problem is that the xml code I have is not creating the layout as in the sketch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other two answers explained pretty well what you were doing wrong. I created a VERY rough layout of how your view should look like just to give you an idea of all the parameters.  This is in no way the best solution but it does replicate what you described in the picture. According to your requirements you can modify as needed.  I have put in some comments that might be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#5981b2">

    <!--This will always be top left of parent-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

    <!--The following two views should be wrapped in a linear a layout
    if you always want them to take up same horizontal space
    regardless of which one has more text-->
    <!--This will always be above subtitle and right of
    image left-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:text="titleText"
        android:textSize="22dp"/>

    <!--This will always be below title and right of
    image Left, if you were to wrap this and above view
    in a linear layout then you can just set that linear
    layout to be right of right image-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageLeft"
        android:text="subtitleText"/>

    <!--************************************-->

    <!--Again you should wrap the following 2 views in
    a linear layout if the icon and number always need
     to take up same space-->
    <!--As for now this image view will always
    be to the right of subtitle-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSubtitle"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"/>

    <!--This text view will always be to the left of
    subtitle, wrapping the above view and this in a linear
    layout will also allow you to center the num (text view)-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSubtitle"
        android:text="num"/>
    <!--************************************-->

    <!--This final view can just be centered vertically
    and as of now will always be to the right of Icon
    but once you wrap the icon and num in a linear layout
    then you can just align in to the right of that layout.-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in this case, the parent layout should be a relative one, like in my code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark the top section as code. Yes only relative layout allows you to align components using layout_toRightOf, layout_toLeftOf, layout_below, layout_above properties.

Answer (score 1):

The two problems that I see are

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:text="Subtitle" />
```

you have `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` when I believe you want

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageLeft"
```

and

```
android:layout_below="@id/titleText"
```

Then for

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon1"
    android:text="14"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

you have

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon1"
```

I think you want

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/subtitleText"
```

and

```
android:layout_below="@id/icon1"
```

you also might want to use `android:layout_centerInParent="vertical"` for `android:id="@+id/icon2"` if you change the height of the parent `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content` but I don't know if that is an option for you. If not then you may need to add some top `padding` to it.

This should get you as close as I can without a screenshot of how it currently looks. Try making those changes and see how it looks. You may have to adjust a few things still but try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"       
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageLeft"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageLeft"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="Titulo"
    android:textSize="22dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageLeft" <!-- add this -->
 <!--  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" remove this -->
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:text="Subtitle" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/titleText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/titleText"
    android:margin_top="10dp"  <!-- add this, choose exact value -->
    android:src="@drawable/valoracion" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/icon1"
    <!-- android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon1"  remove -->
    android:layout_below="@id/icon1"
    android:text="14"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/icon1"  <!-- change to icon1 -->
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1" <!-- also -->
    android:src="@drawable/flecha" />
```